# How to generate an enum of integer from wsdl using SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, enums, wsdl

I am trying to create an enum from my wsdl, I am able to create the enum for string values but when I am trying to create it for integer it is not creating the enum, instead, it is creating big integer.But the same way I am using to create an enum of String from WSDL.Here is what I have done

```
<xs:complexType name="PaymentInfo">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bankAccountNumber" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bankRoutingNumber" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bankAccountType" type="tns:BankAccountType"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cardExpirationDate" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cardNumber" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cardTypeV1sta" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cardTypeOneStop" type="tns:CardTypeOneStop"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleType name="enumType">
            <xs:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
```

I am trying to create an enum cardTypeV1sta where I will have three integers 1,2,3.But when the WSDL is building it is generating BigInteger

```
public class PaymentInfo {
protected String bankAccountNumber;
protected String bankRoutingNumber;
protected String bankAccountType;
protected String cardExpirationDate;
protected String cardNumber;
@XmlElement(name = "cardTypeV1sta")
protected BigInteger cardTypeV1Sta; // here is the problem
protected String cardTypeOneStop;
```

wherein a similar case I am doing

```
<xs:simpleType name="TransactionStatus">
            <xs:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="E"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
```

which is generating perfect enum

```
@XmlType(name = "TransactionStatus")
@XmlEnum
public enum TransactionStatus {

E,
S;

public String value() {
    return name();
}

public static TransactionStatus fromValue(String v) {
    return valueOf(v);
}

}
```

Can anyone help me how I can generate an enum with an integer value from WSDL?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect it to generate? 1,2 and 3 are not valid Enum values in Java, unlike E and S.

Comment: @RobObdeijn i want to generate an enum which contains Three values and contains corresponding integer with them i.e public enum CardTypeV1sta{
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    private final int value;

    private Status(int value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

Comment: I assume you're using JaxB? In that case you can look into TypeSafeEnumMember and TypeSafeEnumClass as described here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Developing_Applications_Using_JAX-WS/files/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingEnum.html